# Navigation bar height changing on hide and unhide

Tags: ios, iphone

In my application I have to show one screen with navigation bar and then by pushing another controller with no navigation bar.
When I come back I again want to show the navigation bar. But, my navigation bar is not visible with complete height.

I set the navigation bar with no translucent, and style opaque.

can you help me anyone.

Comment: some example code will help to foster understanding for the problem

Comment: post code what u have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

In `view controller` where you want to hide `navigation bar` add the below code in `viewWillAppear`

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

So, if you are in some `view controller`:

In `view controller` where you want to show `navigation bar` add the below code in `viewWillAppear`

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

this will hide and show navigation bar perfectly:

in first view controller implement:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

in pushed view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show some code...

or try showing the navigation bar from the view controller you're coming back from just before you tell it to go back... Should avoid the issue. But suspect you're doing something else wrong.